async-sqlite queries fail due to "cannot be shared between threads safely"
I am writing an API using actix-web, and almost all functions are async. I want to make use of an SQLite database, and so I use the  async-sqlite crate to handle that. This crate is based on the rusqlite crate, but is supposed to help with the async aspects of things.
This works fine as long as I am writing to the database, or making queries resulting in a single row response. However, in order to query for more than one row I have to prepare a statement first, but when I do this I get four errors complaining about things cannot be shared between threads safely.
Ex.
error[E0277]: `*mut sqlite3_stmt` cannot be shared between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:7:34
    |
7   |     let _result = match sql_pool.conn(move|conn| {
    |                                  ^^^^ `*mut sqlite3_stmt` cannot be shared between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `Statement<'_>`, the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `*mut sqlite3_stmt`
note: required because it appears within the type `RawStatement`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rusqlite-0.30.0/src/raw_statement.rs:12:12
    |
12  | pub struct RawStatement {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: required because it appears within the type `Statement<'_>`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rusqlite-0.30.0/src/statement.rs:18:12
    |
18  | pub struct Statement<'conn> {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^
    = note: required for `&Statement<'_>` to implement `Send`
note: required because it appears within the type `Option<&Statement<'_>>`
   --> /rustc/eb26296b556cef10fb713a38f3d16b9886080f26/library/core/src/option.rs:563:10
note: required because it appears within the type `Rows<'_>`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rusqlite-0.30.0/src/row.rs:10:12
    |
10  | pub struct Rows<'stmt> {
    |            ^^^^
note: required because it appears within the type `MappedRows<'_, [closure@main.rs:9:73]>`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rusqlite-0.30.0/src/row.rs:143:12
    |
143 | pub struct MappedRows<'stmt, F> {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^
    = note: required for `Unique<MappedRows<'_, [closure@src/main.rs:9:73: 9:78]>>` to implement `Send`
note: required because it appears within the type `RawVec<MappedRows<'_, [closure@main.rs:9:73]>>`
   --> /rustc/eb26296b556cef10fb713a38f3d16b9886080f26/library/alloc/src/raw_vec.rs:51:19
note: required because it appears within the type `Vec<MappedRows<'_, [closure@main.rs:9:73]>>`
   --> /rustc/eb26296b556cef10fb713a38f3d16b9886080f26/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:396:12
note: required by a bound in `Pool::conn`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/async-sqlite-0.2.2/src/pool.rs:181:12
    |
178 |     pub async fn conn<F, T>(&self, func: F) -> Result<T, Error>
    |                  ---- required by a bound in this associated function
...
181 |         T: Send + 'static,
    |            ^^^^ required by this bound in `Pool::conn`

error[E0277]: `RefCell<rusqlite::inner_connection::InnerConnection>` cannot be shared between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:7:34
    |
7   |     let _result = match sql_pool.conn(move|conn| {
    |                                  ^^^^ `RefCell<rusqlite::inner_connection::InnerConnection>` cannot be shared between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `Statement<'_>`, the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `RefCell<rusqlite::inner_connection::InnerConnection>`
    = note: if you want to do aliasing and mutation between multiple threads, use `std::sync::RwLock` instead
note: required because it appears within the type `Connection`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rusqlite-0.30.0/src/lib.rs:377:12
    |
377 | pub struct Connection {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^
    = note: required because it appears within the type `&Connection`
note: required because it appears within the type `Statement<'_>`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rusqlite-0.30.0/src/statement.rs:18:12
    |
18  | pub struct Statement<'conn> {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^
    = note: required for `&Statement<'_>` to implement `Send`
note: required because it appears within the type `Option<&Statement<'_>>`
   --> /rustc/eb26296b556cef10fb713a38f3d16b9886080f26/library/core/src/option.rs:563:10
note: required because it appears within the type `Rows<'_>`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rusqlite-0.30.0/src/row.rs:10:12
    |
10  | pub struct Rows<'stmt> {
    |            ^^^^
note: required because it appears within the type `MappedRows<'_, [closure@main.rs:9:73]>`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rusqlite-0.30.0/src/row.rs:143:12
    |
143 | pub struct MappedRows<'stmt, F> {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^
    = note: required for `Unique<MappedRows<'_, [closure@src/main.rs:9:73: 9:78]>>` to implement `Send`
note: required because it appears within the type `RawVec<MappedRows<'_, [closure@main.rs:9:73]>>`
   --> /rustc/eb26296b556cef10fb713a38f3d16b9886080f26/library/alloc/src/raw_vec.rs:51:19
note: required because it appears within the type `Vec<MappedRows<'_, [closure@main.rs:9:73]>>`
   --> /rustc/eb26296b556cef10fb713a38f3d16b9886080f26/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:396:12
note: required by a bound in `Pool::conn`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/async-sqlite-0.2.2/src/pool.rs:181:12
    |
178 |     pub async fn conn<F, T>(&self, func: F) -> Result<T, Error>
    |                  ---- required by a bound in this associated function
...
181 |         T: Send + 'static,
    |            ^^^^ required by this bound in `Pool::conn`

error[E0277]: `RefCell<BTreeMap<rusqlite::util::small_cstr::SmallCString, usize>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:7:34
    |
7   |     let _result = match sql_pool.conn(move|conn| {
    |                                  ^^^^ `RefCell<BTreeMap<rusqlite::util::small_cstr::SmallCString, usize>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `Statement<'_>`, the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `RefCell<BTreeMap<rusqlite::util::small_cstr::SmallCString, usize>>`
    = note: if you want to do aliasing and mutation between multiple threads, use `std::sync::RwLock` instead
note: required because it appears within the type `ParamIndexCache`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rusqlite-0.30.0/src/util/param_cache.rs:9:19
    |
9   | pub(crate) struct ParamIndexCache(RefCell<BTreeMap<SmallCString, usize>>);
    |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: required because it appears within the type `RawStatement`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rusqlite-0.30.0/src/raw_statement.rs:12:12
    |
12  | pub struct RawStatement {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: required because it appears within the type `Statement<'_>`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rusqlite-0.30.0/src/statement.rs:18:12
    |
18  | pub struct Statement<'conn> {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^
    = note: required for `&Statement<'_>` to implement `Send`
note: required because it appears within the type `Option<&Statement<'_>>`
   --> /rustc/eb26296b556cef10fb713a38f3d16b9886080f26/library/core/src/option.rs:563:10
note: required because it appears within the type `Rows<'_>`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rusqlite-0.30.0/src/row.rs:10:12
    |
10  | pub struct Rows<'stmt> {
    |            ^^^^
note: required because it appears within the type `MappedRows<'_, [closure@main.rs:9:73]>`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rusqlite-0.30.0/src/row.rs:143:12
    |
143 | pub struct MappedRows<'stmt, F> {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^
    = note: required for `Unique<MappedRows<'_, [closure@src/main.rs:9:73: 9:78]>>` to implement `Send`
note: required because it appears within the type `RawVec<MappedRows<'_, [closure@main.rs:9:73]>>`
   --> /rustc/eb26296b556cef10fb713a38f3d16b9886080f26/library/alloc/src/raw_vec.rs:51:19
note: required because it appears within the type `Vec<MappedRows<'_, [closure@main.rs:9:73]>>`
   --> /rustc/eb26296b556cef10fb713a38f3d16b9886080f26/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:396:12
note: required by a bound in `Pool::conn`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/async-sqlite-0.2.2/src/pool.rs:181:12
    |
178 |     pub async fn conn<F, T>(&self, func: F) -> Result<T, Error>
    |                  ---- required by a bound in this associated function
...
181 |         T: Send + 'static,
    |            ^^^^ required by this bound in `Pool::conn`

error[E0277]: `RefCell<hashlink::lru_cache::LruCache<Arc<str>, rusqlite::raw_statement::RawStatement>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:7:34
    |
7   |     let _result = match sql_pool.conn(move|conn| {
    |                                  ^^^^ `RefCell<hashlink::lru_cache::LruCache<Arc<str>, rusqlite::raw_statement::RawStatement>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `Statement<'_>`, the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `RefCell<hashlink::lru_cache::LruCache<Arc<str>, rusqlite::raw_statement::RawStatement>>`
    = note: if you want to do aliasing and mutation between multiple threads, use `std::sync::RwLock` instead
note: required because it appears within the type `StatementCache`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rusqlite-0.30.0/src/cache.rs:61:12
    |
61  | pub struct StatementCache(RefCell<LruCache<Arc<str>, RawStatement>>);
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: required because it appears within the type `Connection`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rusqlite-0.30.0/src/lib.rs:377:12
    |
377 | pub struct Connection {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^
    = note: required because it appears within the type `&Connection`
note: required because it appears within the type `Statement<'_>`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rusqlite-0.30.0/src/statement.rs:18:12
    |
18  | pub struct Statement<'conn> {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^
    = note: required for `&Statement<'_>` to implement `Send`
note: required because it appears within the type `Option<&Statement<'_>>`
   --> /rustc/eb26296b556cef10fb713a38f3d16b9886080f26/library/core/src/option.rs:563:10
note: required because it appears within the type `Rows<'_>`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rusqlite-0.30.0/src/row.rs:10:12
    |
10  | pub struct Rows<'stmt> {
    |            ^^^^
note: required because it appears within the type `MappedRows<'_, [closure@main.rs:9:73]>`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rusqlite-0.30.0/src/row.rs:143:12
    |
143 | pub struct MappedRows<'stmt, F> {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^
    = note: required for `Unique<MappedRows<'_, [closure@src/main.rs:9:73: 9:78]>>` to implement `Send`
note: required because it appears within the type `RawVec<MappedRows<'_, [closure@main.rs:9:73]>>`
   --> /rustc/eb26296b556cef10fb713a38f3d16b9886080f26/library/alloc/src/raw_vec.rs:51:19
note: required because it appears within the type `Vec<MappedRows<'_, [closure@main.rs:9:73]>>`
   --> /rustc/eb26296b556cef10fb713a38f3d16b9886080f26/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:396:12
note: required by a bound in `Pool::conn`
   --> /home/vild/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/async-sqlite-0.2.2/src/pool.rs:181:12
    |
178 |     pub async fn conn<F, T>(&self, func: F) -> Result<T, Error>
    |                  ---- required by a bound in this associated function
...
181 |         T: Send + 'static,
    |            ^^^^ required by this bound in `Pool::conn`


My code looks like this
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, post};
use async_sqlite::{JournalMode, PoolBuilder};


async fn database_lookup(sql_pool: &async_sqlite::Pool) -> Result<String, String> {

    let _result = match sql_pool.conn(move|conn| {
        let mut stmt = conn.prepare("SELECT attribute WHERE resource = :resource").unwrap();
        let rows = stmt.query_map(&[(":resource", "https://test.com")], |row| row.get(0));
        let mut attributes = Vec::new();
        for attr in rows {
            attributes.push(attr);
        }
        Ok(attributes)
    }).await {
        Ok(attrib) => Ok(attrib),
        Err(_e) => return Err("There was an error".to_string())
    };

    return Ok("abc".to_string());
}


#[post("/endpoint")]
async fn endpoint() -> HttpResponse {
    
    let sql_pool = match PoolBuilder::new()
            .path("db.sqlite3")
            .journal_mode(JournalMode::Wal)
            .open()
            .await {
        Ok(con) => con,
        Err(_e) => panic!("Failed to open database")
    };

    let _result = match database_lookup(&sql_pool).await {
        Ok(c) => c,
        Err(_e) => return HttpResponse::BadRequest().body(format!("bad things happen"))
    };

    return HttpResponse::Ok().body(format!("Good stuff"));
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {

    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new().service(
            web::scope("/base")
                .service(endpoint),
        )
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}

Is there another way that I am missing?

Please provide full minimal reproducible example and full compiler error message. Especially show us what are types of your variables, function arguments, etc.

TL;DR is that you are using a multithreading work-stealling runtime, which means that futures you execute may move between OS threads, and for that they must be Send. And for a future to be Send you cannot hold any non-Send types between await points.

Does this answers your question?

I included the full error message. Send seems to be in place (according to error message) but Sync is not.

I have now attached a full program that illustrates the issue. It generates the same errors.
